# I am trying to test this liquidity smart contract code but if shows error. Liquidity is similar to ocaml, tezos's smart contract language.

Tags: ocaml, blockchain

I have been trying to test the first entry point of this game which is play. But when it tries to compile it, there's some error showing. How do I proceed or is there something I am missing?

```
[%%version 0.4]

type game = {
  number : nat;
  bet : tez;
  player : key_hash;
} 

type storage = {
  game : game option;
  oracle_id : address;
}

let%entry play (number : nat) storage = 
  if number>100p then Current.failwith "number must be <=100";
  if 2p.Current.amount()>Current.balance() then Current.failwith"less balance";

  match storage.game with
  |some g -> failwith ("game has already started",g)
  |None -> 
      let bet = Current.amount() in
      let storage = storage.game <- Some {number, bet, player} in
      (([]:operation list),storage)
```

Comment: "there's some error showing"... Which error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to initialize, add this code:

```
let%init storage (oracle_id : address) =
  {game = (None : game option); oracle_id}
```